# How to customise lines in helm buffer

Tags: helm, helm-sources, helm-selection

When calling a helm selection function like `helm-multi-files` I get a `helm` buffer looking like this:

```
Buffers
templates       755       Dired by name  (in '/path/to/dir->
text.md        1320       Markdown       (in '/path/to/fil-> 

Recentf
/path/to/file/text.md
/scp:me@myserver:/home/
```

If I want to create my own version of, say, `helm-multi-files`, how can I customise the lines with the buffer info?

For example I want to modify on which column the buffer mode info  (eg. "`Dired by name`") is printed. Or I want to get rid of the buffer size info (e.g. "`755`").

Do I have to use some attributes when constructing the helm source `(defvar my-helm-source-....)`? Or do I have to customise the function which uses this source `(defun my-helm-list...)`?

Also, long-line truncation for this helm buffer is switch on (resulting in the "`->`" at the end of the line), how can I switch it off when constructing my own version of this function?

Comment: Try here: https://github.com/emacs-helm/helm/wiki/Developing

Comment: @Pedro Thx. I have had a read through and it’s very valuable for overall coding of helm source and helm command, but I couldn’t find anything to customise the lines in the selection buffer. Did I miss something? Is there a special attribute I can use?

Comment: With "(describe-function 'helm-for-files)" and following 'helm-files.el' link ,, it shows 'truncalte-lines' property. Navigate the code could be a good option.